# PHP Translations using diversen/simple-php-translation

Tags: php, translation

I'm trying to follow the [README](https://github.com/diversen/simple-php-translation/blob/master/README.md) file of this [translator package](https://github.com/diversen/simple-php-translation), but I'm not sure I'm following… Please be aware that I have **VERY LITTLE** knowledge of PHP.

I have a project set up something like this:

```
lang/
--en/language.php
--es/language.php

templates/
--blocks/
----header.php
----[…]
--sections/
----home.php
----[…]

boot.php
index.php // This is where I include my templates and boot.php
```

My `boot.php` goes something like this:

```
<?php
include_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$lang = (!empty($_GET['lang'])) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'es';

use diversen\lang;
use diversen\translate\extractor;

$l = new lang();
$l->setDirsInsideDir(__DIR__ . '/lang/');
$l->setDirsInsideDir(__DIR__ . '/templates/');
$l->loadLanguage($lang);

$e = new extractor();
$e->defaultLanguage = $lang;
$e->updateLang();

// This is just a shortcut function
function __($str) {
    return lang::translate($str);
}
```

By including `boot.php` in my "main template", `index.php`, I'd like to add all non-translated strings to their corresponding translation file, but they remain unchanged (ie. nothing is being appended to the translation files)

In my template files I'm using the shortcut function `__()` like so:

```
<?= __('Some string to translate'); ?>
```

And I'm seeing them rendered as `NT: Some string to translate`. I assume `NT` stands for `Not Translated` or something along those lines.

My apache error logs are not showing anything…